# Questions about variables in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I came across a stored procedure in my class and it has me puzzled. Under the alter procedure there are a bunch of variables that are neither declared or set. Are these not "variables" but parameters? I only know of parameters in the SSRS report aspect. I know what parameters do, they pass data, but I am not sure what these are meant for under the alter procedure. Do all of these variable/parameters have to be used? Are they optional?

Anyway, why are they there and how are they different from the declared variables?

```
GO
ALTER procedure [sys].[sp_addmergesubscription] (
    @publication                    sysname,                   
    @subscriber                     sysname = NULL,                
    @subscriber_db                  sysname = NULL,              
    @subscription_type              nvarchar(15) = 'push',            
    @subscriber_type                nvarchar(15) = 'local',            
    @subscription_priority          real        = NULL,                
    @sync_type                      nvarchar(15) = 'automatic',        
    @frequency_type                 int = NULL, -- defaults to 4
    @frequency_interval             int = NULL, -- defaults to 1
    @frequency_relative_interval    int = NULL, -- defaults to 1
    @frequency_recurrence_factor    int = NULL, -- defaults to 0
    @frequency_subday               int = NULL, -- defaults to 8
    @frequency_subday_interval      int = NULL, -- defaults to 1
    @active_start_time_of_day       int = NULL, -- defaults to 0
    @active_end_time_of_day         int = NULL, -- defaults to 235959
    @active_start_date              int = NULL, -- defaults to 0
    @active_end_date                int = NULL, -- defaults to 99991231
    @optional_command_line          nvarchar(4000) = NULL,
    @description                    nvarchar(255) = NULL,
    @enabled_for_syncmgr            nvarchar(5) = NULL, 
    -- Agent offload
    @offloadagent                   bit = 0,
    @offloadserver                  sysname = NULL,
    @use_interactive_resolver       nvarchar(5) = NULL,
    @merge_job_name                 sysname = NULL,
    @hostname                       sysname = NULL
    ) AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    /*
    ** Declarations.
    */
    declare @retcode                int
    declare @subnickname            binary(6)
    declare @priority               real
    declare @subid                  uniqueidentifier
    declare @pubid                  uniqueidentifier    
    declare @subscriber_typeid      smallint
    declare @subscriber_srvid       int
    declare @merge_jobid            binary(16)            
    declare @subscription_type_id   int      
    declare @distproc               nvarchar(300)
    declare @command                nvarchar(255)
    declare @inactive               tinyint
    declare @subscriber_bit         smallint
    declare @global                 tinyint        
    declare @push                   tinyint        
    declare @sync_typeid            tinyint
    declare @nosync                 tinyint        
    declare @automatic              tinyint        
    declare @distributor            sysname
    declare @distribdb              sysname
    declare @publisher              sysname
    declare @publisher_db           sysname
    declare @found                  int
    declare @datasource_type        int
    DECLARE @platform_nt            binary
    declare @use_interactive_bit    bit
    declare @internal               sysname
    declare @REPOLEVersion_90           int
                ,@publishingservername sysname
    declare @compatlevel int

    /* make sure current database is enabled for merge replication */
    exec @retcode=sys.sp_MSCheckmergereplication
    if @@ERROR<>0 or @retcode<>0
        return (1)

    /*
    ** Initializations.
    */
    set @datasource_type = 0    /* Default SQL Server */
    set @platform_nt = 0x1    
    SET @nosync                = 2          
    SET @automatic            = 1          
    set @inactive            = 0
    SET @subscriber_bit        = 4     
    set @global                = 1
    set @push                = 0
    set @pubid                = NULL           
    set @publisher            = publishingservername()
    set @publisher_db        = DB_NAME()
    select @found            = 1       /
            ,@publishingservername = publishingservername()
    set @REPOLEVersion_90    = 90
```

Comment: @sqluser, please do not make fairly minor formatting changes when there's more to work on in the actual text.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I apologize can you please clarify?

Comment: My comment was irrelevant to the question as such; I was just addressing a user's edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about `@publication`, then it is a parameter of a stored procedure. This parameter doesn't have a default value, so it has to be specified when calling the procedure. Other parameters, like `@subscriber` have default values, so they are optional.

Stored procedures can have [parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260(v=sql.105).aspx).

> A stored procedure communicates with the calling program through its
>   parameters. When a program executes a stored procedure, it can pass
>   values to the stored procedure through the parameters of the stored
>   procedure. These values can be used as standard variables in the
>   Transact-SQL programming language. The stored procedure can also
>   return values to the calling program through OUTPUT parameters. A
>   stored procedure can have as many as 2100 parameters, with each
>   parameter having a name, data type, direction, and default value.

Some of them may have [default values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx).

> You can create a stored procedure with optional parameters by
>   specifying a default value for optional parameters. When the stored
>   procedure is executed, the default value is used if no other value has
>   been specified.

Comment: So then parameters within a SQL procedure are more than likely going to be used for a calling program? At least in this case?

Comment: The caller of the stored procedure specifies parameter values for each call. Usually these values are used inside the procedure and affect the logic of the procedure. So, parameters are used by both the caller and the procedure. Some parameters can be declared as `OUTPUT`. If procedure changes value of such parameter, the changed value can be seen by the caller.